# Solution Package Deployment

Tags: deployment

I have a solution Package which comprises of multiple features, Events receivers, layouts, timerjobs, webparts and custom Master Page. In my Central Administration, I have two web applications. I would like to use the same package(with Different GUIDs) for each web application. One webapplication is http://intranet.swl.com. The other web application is http://team.swl.com. I would like to use the same branding, web parts and event receivers for team site as main site. I am getting error when I try to install the solution package to http://team.swl.com. Its says

"the solution is currently installed in the farm to the directory "swl.master". Unistall the existing feature before you install a new version of the solution"

Please let me know if there is any other easy way to handle this.

Comment: For your information you cannot deploy Event receivers particular to a web application. Event receivers will be deployed globally.

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange requirement to have the same package with different GUIDs. In common case you install package to the farm

```
Add-SPSolution C:\test.wsp
```

If you run this command twice you can see the wsp file is an unique value for this action.

> Add-SPSolution :  A solution with the same name "test.wsp" or id
>   "4b3dbe7a-6fbe-4361-9731-ab111fa22ef1" already exists in the solution
>   store.

When the solution is added to the solution storage you can deploy it to any web as you wish. You can control it through CA (system settings -> manage farm solutions).

[image]

Some solution should be globally deployed.

If you would like to update old version of solution to new, see [update solution actions](http://blog.incworx.com/blog/sharepoint-administrators-blog/how-to-update-an-existing-sharepoint-2010-solution-quickly-and-easily).